# Problems book on Lie groups and Lie algebras for physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, education, lie-algebra

I am trying to get a better gras of Lie groups and Lie algebras and I was wondering if there's any book or general resource with problems and solutions in order to learn through practice.